# Reverse for 'service_fee' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['fees/(?P<service_id>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error and I couldn't find why? Please help me with this error. Below is the code from my project

**urls.py**

```
path("fees/<int:service_id>", views.service_rates_view, name='service_fee')
```

**index.html**

```
{% for service in main_services %}
    <a href="{% url 'emitr:service_fee' service.id %}">{{ service.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**view.py**

```
def service_fee_view(request, service_id):
    service = Service.objects.get(pk=service_id)
    subservices = service.subservice_set.all()

    return render(request, 'emitr/service.html', {
        'service': service,
        'subservices': subservices
    })
```

Comment: That means typically that your service.id in the url tag is empty

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the name of the fbv is matching? In urls.py, you wrote it `service_rates_view` in `views.service_rates_view`, but `service_fee_view` in the view.py

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your **service.id** is empty.

Since Django [models require a primary key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields), you could use that instead

**views.py**

```
    ...
    path("fees/<service_id>/", views.service_rates_view, name='service_fee')
    ...
```

**index.html**

```
{% for service in main_services %}
    <a href="{% url 'emitr:service_fee' service.pk %}">{{ service.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

You can also look into [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) and [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) if they may be of help.